# React failed to compile reactLifecyclesCompat error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, reactstrap

I'm having problem in react. Its compilation error says:

> **Failed to compile**
>
> ```
> ./node_modules/reactstrap/dist/reactstrap.es.js
> Attempted import error: 'react-lifecycles-compat' does not contain a default export (imported as 'reactLifecyclesCompat').
> ```

[image: Error screenshot]

I have the following dependencies

```json
"dependencies": {
  "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
  "react": "^16.7.0",
  "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
  "react-lifecycles-compat": "^3.0.4",
  "react-scripts": "2.1.2",
  "react-transition-group": "^2.5.2",
  "reactstrap": "^7.0.0",
  "uuid": "^3.3.2"
}
```

Then I created one `AppNavbar` component, which is just a simple navbar, at location "src/components/" and below is my `AppNavbar` component code, it exports at the end of file.

```jsx
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    Collapse,
    Navbar,
    NavbarToggler,
    NavbarBrand,
    Nav,
    NavItem,
    NavLink,
    Container
} from 'reactstrap';

class AppNavbar extends Component {
    state = {
        isOpen: false
    }

    toggle = () => {
        this.setState({
            isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar color="dark" dark expand="sm" className="mb-5">
                    <Container>
                        <NavbarBrand href="/">Shopping List!</NavbarBrand>
                        <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggle} />
                        <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
                            <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>
                                <NavItem>
                                    <NavLink href="https://about.me">About</NavLink>
                                </NavItem>
                            </Nav>
                        </Collapse>
                    </Container>
                </Navbar>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default AppNavbar;
```

Then to show it on the page, I import that `AppNavbar` into App.js like this:

```jsx
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AppNavbar from './components/AppNavbar';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <AppNavbar />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a fault in your code but in the way `reactstrap` imports a dependency it needs. Have a look at: https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/issues/1343.

Comment: Yes, I came across this and for now I used reactstrap 6.1.0, which works fine for now! Thanks for the answer